# Login to comment: not just user and email

Tags: user-registration

I am working on a govt blog. where only the govt can post, but citizens can comment on the posts. Commentators cannot be anonymous. The site will need each commentators' real name and area, which will be visible to all visitors. (I don't need to know commentators' email addresses.) Is there a way to add this specific login requirement?

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: @toscho, lol, but I was never impressed with that rant. The purpose of having a name is so other people can identify you therefor it is more important what they name you then how you name yourself. In this case the name can be the name used on official govt papers, whether it is what the person want to call himself or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add this kind of functionality, but it is unlikely to always work. You can not force people to identify their real life ID on the internet. Even geographical detection based on IP address is problematic and easy to avoid using proxies.

If you want people to willingly identify themselves on your site you need to offer them an incentive to do that.

As for the technical aspects, email is a must for creating a user, if you give up on asking for one then you can not create a user, and therefor you don't have the ability to login.